# Primefaces Datatable count all rows after filtering

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I work with jsf and have a primefaces datatable that enables filtering.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{tcsInstanceBean.tcsJList}" var="return" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="550" 
                    widgetVar="returnTable"
                    emptyMessage="Nothing found matching given criteria"
                    filteredValue="#{tcsInstanceBean.filteredTcsJList}"
                    styleClass="returnTable, selectable"
                    headerClass="returnTableHeader"
                    rowClasses="returnTableOddRow,returnTableEvenRow"
                    resizableColumns="true">

                    <p:column class="returnColumn" style="width:40%;"
                        sortBy="#{return.path}"
                        filterBy="#{return.path.fileName}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <f:facet name="header">Job Path</f:facet>
                        <a href="file:///#{return.path}" target="_blank">#{return.path.fileName}</a>
                    </p:column>


</p:dataTable>
```

I want to output all total rows visible after filtering.
At the moment i just count the list and output it.

```
jobsCounter = "We found " + tcsJList.size() + " Jobs!";
```

How can I count all visible rows at the moment after filtering ?

Comment: Use a lazy datamodel and you **know** how many rows you have after filtering

Comment: I don't want to use paginator. My table should be scrollable.

Comment: Lazydatamodel is independent of paginating or scrolling....

Comment: Okay thanks i'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

Write a method like

```
public int count(){
  if(getTcsInstanceBean().filteredTcsJList!=null){
    return getTcsInstanceBean().filteredTcsJList.size();
  }
  else {
    return getcsInstanceBean().tcsJList.size();
  }
}
```

or use the currentPageReportTemplate

```
<p:dataTable value="#{tcsInstanceBean.tcsJList}" var="return" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="550" 
                widgetVar="returnTable"
                emptyMessage="Nothing found matching given criteria"
                filteredValue="#{tcsInstanceBean.filteredTcsJList}"
                styleClass="returnTable, selectable"
                headerClass="returnTableHeader"
                rowClasses="returnTableOddRow,returnTableEvenRow"
                resizableColumns="true"
                paginator="true"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}"
        currentPageReportTemplate="We found {totalRecords}, Jobs!">

                <p:column class="returnColumn" style="width:40%;"
                    sortBy="#{return.path}"
                    filterBy="#{return.path.fileName}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <f:facet name="header">Job Path</f:facet>
                    <a href="file:///#{return.path}" target="_blank">#{return.path.fileName}</a>
                </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```